# Gives me this error in gplus-api using JS

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus, google-api-js-client

Hello i just started learning gplus-api signin using javascript but i came across a error that says this **Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').**
 This is my code i have referred to this site but didn;t help me! https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head></head>
 <body>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>

    <meta name="google-signin-clientid" content="MY_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" />
    <meta name="google-signin-requestvisibleactions" content="http://schema.org/AddAction" />
    <meta name="google-signin-cookiepolicy" content="single_host_origin" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      var po = document.createElement('script');
      po.type = "text/javascript";
      po.async = true;
      po.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js";
      var s = document.getElementByTagName('script');
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(po,s);
  });

 function render() {

  // Additional params including the callback, the rest of the params will
  // come from the page-level configuration.
   var additionalParams = {
     'callback': signinCallback
  };

  // Attach a click listener to a button to trigger the flow.
   var signinButton = document.getElementById('signinButton');
   signinButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
       gapi.auth.signIn(additionalParams); // Will use page level configuration
    });
 }

  function signinCallback(authResult) {
      if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
   // Update the app to reflect a signed in user
   // Hide the sign-in button now that the user is authorized, for   example:
      document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style',             'display: none');
    } else {
    // Update the app to reflect a signed out user
    // Possible error values:
   //   "user_signed_out" - User is signed-out
   //   "access_denied" - User denied access to your app
   //   "immediate_failed" - Could not automatically log in the user
   console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
   }
  }
 </script>
  <button id="signinButton">Sign in with Google</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**my js origin is http://localhost:8080, also when i try to load this url it gives me 404 error**
*please help to solve me this error!*

Answer (score 0):

You must run a web server (even locally) when working with Google+ Sign in. A simple example is to run Python with your port set to 8080:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

You can also configure / run Apache or another server for local testing.